# how to import data in farsi/persian language in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap data from a persian website. It is showing perfect sample response in google chrome but, when I am going to insert that data in Mysql it is showing different character/text.

[image]

if someone can help its appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: What is the collation of the table?

Comment: thanks it is utf8mb4_general_ci